# Never return in a Flatmap with Swift's Combine

Tags: swift, rx-swift, combine

In RxSwift, a flatMap operator can easily return a non-completing Observable. Let's say we have this (contrived and silly) Observable chain:

```
let repo = DataRepository()

Observable
    .just(Int.random(in: 0 ..< 1000))
    .flatMap { num -> Observable<String> in
        if num == 42 {
            return .never()
        }

        return repo
            .fetchData()
            .filter { $0.statusCode == 200 }
            .map { $0.data.title }
    }
```

With Combine, the closest I can get is something like this (haven't tried to compile, but you get the idea):

```
Just(Int.random(in: 0 ..< 1000))
    .flatMap { num -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> in
        if num == 42 {
            return Empty<String, Never>(completeImmediately: false).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

        return repo
            .fetchData()
            .filter { $0.statusCode == 200 }
            .map { $0.data.title }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

I'm okay-ish with this solution, but I see two problems that I would like to avoid:

1) The Combine solution is somewhat more verbose to achieve the same thing.

2) I have to call `eraseToAnyPublisher()` on both returned Publishers, else the return types don't match. I believe calling `eraseToAnyPublisher()` prevents Swift from applying some internal optimizations (I can't find the article I read about this optimization anymore; the information is scarce around this)

Does anyone have a better approach to handling this example scenario?

Comment: First thing. Returning `Observable.never()` is a really bad idea here. Your flatMap will never complete as a result of doing that. Better would be to return `Observable.empty()`.

Comment: Second, Yes you would still need to `eraseToAnyPublisher()` which you say will stop some internal optimization, but that is optimization that RxSwift doesn't even provide so if the latter's performance is acceptable to you, I'm sure the former's will be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to lift any conditional logic into operators.

Conditions under which you emit something like `Observable.never` are best captured in a filter, that way you get the "never" behavior for free.

Example:

```
Just(Int.random(in: 0 ..< 1000))
        .filter { $0 != 42 }
        .flatMap {
            return repo
                .fetchData()
                .filter { $0.statusCode == 200 }
                .map { $0.data.title }
        }
```

I don't know enough about the types in `DataRepository` to know if you need to type erase inside the `flatMap` closure.

Comment: Yeah I realize that's an option, as I said my example is a bit contrived. The approach you suggest does not hold up in more advanced use-cases. For example, when you have a conditional statement that relies on the values of multiple Observables, you cannot use a simple filter. In RxSwift you could use `combineLatest` and return a new Observable (or `.never()` if nothing should be emitted), followed by a `flatMap`. That's what I'm struggling to reproduce with Combine, at least without using `eraseToAnyPublisher()`

Comment: Anything you can do with values inside `flatMap` you can do inside `filter`, I'm not sure why you couldn't use a `filter` for more advanced use cases. This stops you having to create a new `Publisher` inside your `flatMap` closure and subsequently having to type erase it which is what you were looking to prevent in the first place.

Comment: If the logic inside `flatMap` doesn't resolve to a boolean like it does in the example you provided, then use the appropriate operator and `flatMap` the result from that.

Comment: By only operating on the `Output`s of `Publisher`s you never get into the business of creating a new `Publisher`.

There are scenarios where you'll want to do just that, as an example using `flatMap` on a given `Result<Success, Failure>` to only emit the `Success` value. I've not found a way to avoid type erasure here, although I perform it on the result of the `flatMap` rather than inside the closure which admittedly is still more verbose than Rx. It's the result of `Combine` operators being built up of concrete implementations, Rx hides them behind protocols and gets type erasure that way.

Comment: You're right, any logic that resolves to a boolean can be placed inside a filter as well. What I mean in my comment is that a conditional statement that relies on multiple variables and can be processed in a `combineLatest`+`flatMap`. If I want to apply the conditional logic in the `filter`, I'll have to do extra work: `combineLatest` then has to map to a tuple of its arguments, `filter` will have to perform the logic, and finally `flatMap` would be called to do the remainder work normally done directly in the `flatMap`. So that's more verbose/messy as well.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer does not answer the original question, it only gives suggestions on how to avoid it.

But there are legitimate situations where this behavior is needed, such as a Timer, that you don't want to tick and consume resources.

The code in the question is almost correct, but it needs to be:

```swift
Just(Int.random(in: 0 ..< 1000))
    .map { num -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> in
        if num == 42 {
            return Empty<String, Never>(completeImmediately: false).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

        return repo
            .fetchData()
            .filter { $0.statusCode == 200 }
            .map { $0.data.title }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .switchToLatest()
```

---

A more practical use case, for example a timer that ticks every second, and can be paused.

```
let isPaused: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>

let pausableTimer = isPaused.
    .map { isPaused in
        if isPaused {
            return Empty<Void, Never>()
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            return Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
                .autoconnect()
                .map { _ in }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
    .switchToLatest()
```

You don't want to use someting like `CombineLatest`, because the Timer would keep on ticking, while it's paused and the output even is ignored.